# When left-clicking on TrayIcon JFrame disappears and appears again

Tags: java, system-tray

i have a problem with the **Tray**.
The program works but there is a problem.

> **Should be:**

When i left click on the TrayIcon (TNA) the JFrame should disappear.
When i left click again on it the JFrame should appear.

> **At the moment:**

When i click on the TrayIcon it the JFrame disappear and fast appears again and after this it works fine.
But always when im first time clicking on it it disappears and appears.

```
package IReminderMain;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import GUI.IReminderMainFrame;


public class IReminderStart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /** 
         * New EDT
         * */
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
                try{
                    //New JFrame Main
                    new IReminderMainFrame();



                }
                catch (Exception e){

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}









package GUI;

import GUI.ImageIoReader;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Tray extends MouseAdapter {

    private boolean visible;
    private boolean vis;
    private Image img;
    private JFrame neu;

    String i = new String("img/IReminderIcon.png");
    MouseListener mouseL = new Mouse();


    private void erstelleImage(){
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(ImageIoReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(i));
            System.out.println("ImageIoRead Tray: Image erstellt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO throw to user input
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------Konstruktor------------------------------------------------------------

    public Tray(boolean visible, JFrame neu, boolean vis) {
        System.out.println("Tray: Konstruktor aufgerufen");
        erstelleImage();
        this.visible = visible;
        this.neu = neu;
        this.vis = vis;     

        TrayIcon trayIcon = null;
        //--------------------------------------------if------------------------------------------------------------
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {

            SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            //------------------------------------------ActionListener---------------------------------------------------------------------
            ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            //------------------------------------------/ActionListener---------------------------------------------------------------------

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu("IReminder");
            MenuItem beenden = new MenuItem("Beenden");
            beenden.addActionListener(listener);
            popup.add(beenden);

            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(img, "IReminder", popup);
            //------------------------------------------MouseListener---------------------------------------------------------------------
            MouseListener mouseListener = new Mouse() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Tray: Mouse Clicked");
                    boolean visible = getvisFrame();
                    System.out.println("Tray: getvisFrame"+ getVisibleFrame());

                    if (visible == true) {
                        getFrame().setVisible(false);
                        System.out.println("Tray: false");
                        setvisFrame(false);


                    } else  {
                        System.out.println("Tray: true");
                        getFrame().setVisible(true);
                        setvisFrame(true);                  
                    }       
                }       
            };
            //------------------------------------------/MouseListener---------------------------------------------------------------------
            trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

            try {
                System.out.println("Tray: Try");
                trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
                tray.add(trayIcon);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }

        } else {

        }
        //--------------------------------------------/Ende if------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    //--------------------------------------------/Konstruktor------------------------------------------------------------

    public boolean getVisibleFrame() {
        System.out.println("Tray: Getter Visibility Frame");
        return visible;
    }

    public JFrame getFrame(){
        System.out.println("Tray: Getter Frame");
        return neu;
    }
    public boolean getvisFrame(){
        return vis;
    }

    public void setvisFrame(boolean vis){
        System.out.println("Tray: Getter Frame");
        this.vis = vis;
    }

    public void setFrame(JFrame frame){
        System.out.println("Tray: Getter Frame");
        neu = frame;
    }
}










package GUI;


import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class MyWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

        System.out.println("The Window is closing but the program is still running!");      
    }
}








package GUI;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }



}







package GUI;


import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class Look {

    private LookAndFeel look;
    private LookAndFeel newLook;


    /** 
     * Konstruktor: Erstellt und aktiviert das Look and Feel
     * */
    public Look(LookAndFeel look){
        setLookAndFeel(look);
        activateLookAndFeel();
        System.out.println("Look: Look and Feel done");
    }

    /** 
     * Methode: Setzt das Look and Feel
     * */
    public void activateLookAndFeel(){
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(newLook = look);
            System.out.println("Look: Look and Feel activated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Setter: Setzt das Objekt new Look and Feel der Variable look
     * */
    private void setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeel look){
        this.look = look;
        System.out.println("Look: Look and Feel set");
    }

    public LookAndFeel getLookAndFeel(){
        return newLook;

    }

}







package GUI;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public abstract class JWindows extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8698706321873075551L;

    public abstract void getLook();
    public abstract void getNewTitle();
    public abstract void getCloseOperation();

    public abstract void getNewLayout();

    public abstract void getVisible();  
    public abstract void getIcon();

}








package GUI;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;

public class IReminderMainFrame extends JWindows {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -21323574593098624L;

    boolean frameVisible = getVisableReminder();
    private WindowListener wListener;

    public IReminderMainFrame(){

        getLook();
        getNewTitle();
        getNewLayout();
        ImagePath i = new ImagePath("img/IReminderIcon.png");
        setIconImage(i.getImage());
        getIcon();
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getVisible();




        addWindowListener(wListener);
    }

    private boolean getVisableReminder() {
        return this.isVisible();
    }

    @Override
    public void getLook() {
        NimbusLookAndFeel nimbus = new NimbusLookAndFeel();
        new Look(nimbus);
    }

    @Override
    public void getNewTitle() {
        setTitle("IReminder");
    }

    @Override
    public void getCloseOperation() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void getNewLayout() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    }

    @Override
    public void getVisible() {
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private void setListenerFrame (WindowListener listener){
        this.wListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void getIcon() {

        new Tray(isVisible(), this, frameVisible);
        //---------------------------------------WindowListener-----------------------------------------------------------
        WindowListener frameListener = new MyWindowListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

                int answer = JOptionPane
                        .showConfirmDialog(
                                IReminderMainFrame.this,
                                "Das Programm wird im Hintergrund fortgesetzt \nFenster schliessen?",
                                "Programm wird nicht beendet",
                                JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

                if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Das Fenster wird geschlossen, jedoch wird das Programm im Hintergrund noch ausgeführt!");
                    IReminderMainFrame.this.setVisible(false);
                }

                System.out.println("Fenster nicht geschlossen");

            }

        };
        setListenerFrame(frameListener);

    }





}







package GUI;

public class ImagePath extends ImageIoReader {

    /** 
     * Konstruktor: ImagePath sendet den String zu ImageIoReader, das Image kann man sich 
     * dann über die Methode getImage(); sich von hier oder der Vaterklasse ziehen.
     * */

    public ImagePath(String s){
        /** 
         * Sendet den String zu ImageIoReader Klasse
         * */
        super (s);
    }

}








package GUI;


import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageIoReader {

    private String i;
    private BufferedImage img;

    /** 
     * Konstruktor: übergibt den Pfad des Images and die Methode und erstellt dann das img
     * */
    public ImageIoReader(String i){
        setImage(i);
        createImage();

        System.out.println("ImageIoRead: Konstruktor ImageIoRead ausgeführt");
    }
    /** 
     * Methode: erstellt das img und speichert es in die Variable ab
     * */
    private void createImage(){
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(ImageIoReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(i));
            System.out.println("ImageIoRead: Image erstellt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO throw to user input
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    /** 
     * Braucht ein String der den Pfad des Img übergibt
     * */
    private void setImage(String i){
        this.i = i;
        System.out.println("ImageIoRead: Imagepfad in Variable i gespeichert");
    }
    /** 
     * Gibt ein Image zurück an den aufrufer
     * */
    public BufferedImage getImage(){
        System.out.println("ImageIoRead: Image aufgerufen");
        return img;
    }



}
```

> **This is the Part of the important Code:**

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Tray extends MouseAdapter {

    private boolean visible;
    private boolean vis;
    private Image img;
    private JFrame neu;

    String i = new String("img/IReminderIcon.png");
    MouseListener mouseL = new Mouse();

    //Start Constructor----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public Tray(boolean visible, JFrame neu, boolean vis) {
        System.out.println("Tray: Konstruktor aufgerufen");
        erstelleImage();
        this.visible = visible;  //IReminderMainFrame isVisible()
        this.neu = neu;
        this.vis = vis;         //IReminderMainFrame from method to a variable isVisible()

        TrayIcon trayIcon = null;

        //Start if--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {

            SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            //Start ActionListener---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };
            //***End ActionListener---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu("IReminder");
            MenuItem beenden = new MenuItem("Beenden");
            beenden.addActionListener(listener);
            popup.add(beenden);

            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(img, "IReminder", popup);

            //Start MouseListener---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            MouseListener mouseListener = new Mouse() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Tray: Mouse Clicked");
                    boolean visible = getvisFrame();
                    System.out.println("Tray: getvisFrame"+ getVisibleFrame());

                    if (visible == true) {
                        getFrame().setVisible(false);
                        System.out.println("Tray: false");
                        setvisFrame(false);


                    } else  {
                        System.out.println("Tray: true");
                        getFrame().setVisible(true);
                        setvisFrame(true);                  
                    }       
                }       
            };

            //***End MouseListener---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

            try {
                System.out.println("Tray: Try");
                trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
                tray.add(trayIcon);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }

        } else {

        }

        //***End if--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    //***Constructor end----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //Start instance method--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private void erstelleImage(){
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(ImageIoReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(i));
            System.out.println("ImageIoRead Tray: Image erstellt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO throw to user input
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    public boolean getVisibleFrame() {
        System.out.println("Tray: Getter visible Frame");
        return visible;
    }

    public JFrame getFrame(){
        System.out.println("Tray: Getter JFrame");
        return neu;
    }
    public boolean getvisFrame(){
        return vis;
    }

    public void setvisFrame(boolean vis){
        System.out.println("Tray: Setter vis JFrame");
        this.vis = vis;
    }

    public void setFrame(JFrame frame){
        System.out.println("Tray: Setter JFrame");
        neu = frame;
    }

    //***End instance method--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

I really hope you can help me with that and thanks to all helpers!
PS: Im sorry for my English.

Edited the code (sysout)
Here is the sysout when i run and click sometime on the trayicon

```
Look: Look and Feel set
Look: Look and Feel activated
Look: Look and Feel done
ImageIoRead: Imagepfad in Variable i gespeichert
ImageIoRead: Image erstellt
ImageIoRead: Konstruktor ImageIoRead ausgeführt
ImageIoRead: Image aufgerufen
Tray: Konstruktor aufgerufen
ImageIoRead Tray: Image erstellt
Tray: Try
Tray: Mouse Clicked
Tray: Getter visible Frame
Tray: getvisFramefalse
Tray: true
Tray: Getter JFrame
Tray: Setter vis JFrame
Tray: Mouse Clicked
Tray: Getter visible Frame
Tray: getvisFramefalse
Tray: Getter JFrame
Tray: false
Tray: Setter vis JFrame
Tray: Mouse Clicked
Tray: Getter visible Frame
Tray: getvisFramefalse
Tray: true
Tray: Getter JFrame
Tray: Setter vis JFrame
Tray: Mouse Clicked
Tray: Getter visible Frame
Tray: getvisFramefalse
Tray: Getter JFrame
Tray: false
Tray: Setter vis JFrame
```

Comment: Why not check the state of the frame and simply switch it's state, rather the trying to maintain some kind of flag?

Comment: My Code looks a little irritated now (Tray Class) .
My first idea was like you say check frame and switch state.
But i had many problems with that thats why i do here a workaround.
First i was simply switching it but the JFrame was going flashing like off on off on off on

Comment: in tray Class i check also the isVisible() from the JFrame but on a workaround

Comment: methods name are not the best in the Tray class sorry for that.
The names are bad because i tried to fix the problem

Comment: I removed the code snippet markup from your post. Code snippets are for runnable web samples (like Javascript). Use the **Code Sample { }** button instead.